# Mitochondria variability per tissue in humans?

Tags: metabolism, cancer, bioenergetics

I would like to know the distribution of mitochondrial content per tissue type in humans. I understand the simple metric that energetically active or energy requiring tissues will have more mitochondrial content, however is there any study/link for a more quantitative estimate ?

Comment: Welcome to Bio.SE. You ask for mitochondrial content ***per*** tissue type? Are you asking for help in searching for a proper database or are you expecting folks to sum up every tissue type in man along with its mitochondrial content? I would suggest to specify your question.

Comment: check [this](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/jcp.1041360316/abstract;jsessionid=736A40D5DFB3646B64F1220322D26844.f04t02) out. Not able to access it as of now.

Comment: @WYSIWYG I think we convergently cited the same paper :P

Comment: @MarchHo perhaps. [This](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/jcp.1041430122/abstract) is another one. Can't access this one too as of now.

Answer (score 2):

BioNumbers is a great site to answer this kind of question.

[This search](http://bionumbers.hms.harvard.edu/search.aspx?log=y&task=searchbytrmorg&trm=mitochondria%20per%20cell&time=2015/03/08%2004:18:16.577&rpp=100) produced a link to [this paper](http://kirschner.med.harvard.edu/files/bionumbers/A%20comparison%20of%20mtDNA%20per%20mt,%20virtual%20mt%20number%20per%20cell,%20mt%20DNA%20per%20cell,%20Cyaa3%20per%20mt,%20and%20Cyaa3%20per%20cell%20in%20five%20cell%20types%20from%20four%20mammalian%20species.pdf) , which has measurements for mitochondria per cell for multiple species and cell type.

[image]